# Can a person be described as being "ill read"?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

I recently read a comment disparaging an individual as being "ill read" as opposed to well-read. Is this an accepted usage?

Answer (score 3):

Whether "accepted" or not, it is used. While it offers no definition, [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ill-read/examples?page=1) gives over 20 examples of *ill-read* in print, many of them current. In addition to being used to define someone who is ignorant or uninformed,

> Unfortunately, ill-informed and ill-read people are dishing out worn out judgments.
>   — *Archive 2007-05-01*

*ill-read* is also used to refer to someone who has not read much about a specific area or topic

> I’m sadly ill-read when it comes to short stories and poetry.
>   — *Writer Unboxed » Blog Archive » AUTHOR INTERVIEW: Anne Harris*

The other sense in which it is used is to describe a piece of writing as being either misread or not read by as wide an audience as it might deserve:

> His only accomplishment, as far as I can see is that he was a celebrity, in the meaning remarked by the late Dan Boorstin, in his ground-breaking, and ill-read book of media criticism, The Image (1961), for which there there is but one criterion: Tim Russert was known mainly for being known.
>   — *Tim Russert Has Passed Away*

The various meanings of the term are usually obvious from their context.

Comment: Those cases appear to be plays on "ill-bred", which has fallen out of democratic favour.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine. In this context, *ill* conforms to MW's [third definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ill):

> not suited to circumstances or not to one's advantage

I would hyphenate it as a phrasal adjective, like *well-read* -- e.g., *ill-read*.

Comment: *well read* doesn't usually take a hyphen except it modifies a noun directly, e.g. *well-read scholar*, and even then, some would still consider hyphenation optional...

Comment: btw, that wasn't my down-vote!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more a concern for style than usage. Plenty of English idioms don't have mirror complements, and that's ok. We can still identify and accept them. Perhaps there is a metalogic at work here that says for every phrase we coin, it's reasonable to expect there is a reverse for every obverse side. But there is a price.

As a student I remember crafting these complements several times in my compositions. I can't recall one at the moment, but my best teachers always circled them and added a red "NO" somewhere in the margin. As a composition instructor myself, I was more long-winded: "I understand what you meant. In fact, now I'm thinking about it. What is the topic of your paper again?" My best students did not repeat the practice. And I never thought my teachers were short-winded; they were terse.

English idioms make it difficult to perceive a driving logic behind the language. Which is the lesson; there isn't one. They are sometimes formed by sediment, sometimes by metamorphosis, and sometimes from freshly molten stuff. Sooner or later, you have to take a lot of its features at face value alone.

Comment: Context and audience is key. A more creative medium is more forgiving in regards to playing around with idioms.

Answer (score 1):

As attribute, *ill* can have three meanings:

- poor in quality
- harmful
- (especially of fortune) not favorable

About the usage of the hyphen, the NOAD has the following note, which apply for both *ill* and *well*:

> The adverb *well* is often used in combination with past participles to form compound adjectives: *well-adjusted*, *well-intentioned*, *well-known*, and so on. As far as hyphenation is concerned, there are three general rules:
>   1. if the compound adjective is placed before the noun (i.e., in the attributive position), it should be hyphenated (*a well-intentioned remark*);
>   2. if the compound adjective is preceded by an adverb (*much*, *very*, *surprisingly*, etc.), the compound adjective is open (*a thoroughly well prepared student*);
>   3. if the compound adjective is placed after the noun or verb (i.e., in the predicate position), it may, but need not, be hyphenated (*her remark was well-intentioned or her remark was well intentioned*).
>   Likewise, other, similar compounds with *better*, *best*, *ill*, *little*, *lesser*, *least*, etc., are hyphenated before the noun (*a little-known author*), often open after a noun or verb (*the author was little known*), and open if modified by an adverb (*a very little known author*).

Answer (score 0):

One could not be *well at ease*, could they? Well, neither could one be *ill read*!

Seriously, though, while *ill read* is not a standard phrase, its meaning would certainly not be difficult to deduce, and it makes for colorful writing/reading.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just agreed with Jimi Oke here. Particularly after checking [actual occurrences in written form](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ill%20read&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but I'm not sure I can endorse his statement that the meaning of this non-standard phrase wouldn't be difficult to deduce.

*Ill[-]* used as a prefix in this way generally modifies an *activity which has been badly performed*. But in practice the opposite of well-read wouldn't normally be understood to imply a person who read badly - it would be a person who hadn't really read much "quality" literature *at all*.

Are we talking about a person who can't read very well at all? Who *can*, but doesn't bother? Or who only reads trashy pot-boilers? I don't know, and I don't see how anyone else can. We can all have opinions, but it's not a standard phrase - so who's to say what it should mean?

Comment: Your Ngram link is useful in accessing actual use in print, but the graph itself is misleading because of the high number of misreadings of the Roman numeral III for _ill_ and the inclusion of _ill_ as in _sick_. I thought refining the search for _ill-read man_ or _ill-read person_ might help, but I got no results.

Comment: Well, relatively speaking there weren't many occurences anyway. I scanned quite a few myself, and saw a few pre-1850 that *might* have covered OP's sense. But in the more recent stuff I only found one candidate. I only put the link there to show that it's nowhere near a standard turn of phrase now, and probably never was.

Comment: Here's an attempt at a refined [search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22ill-read%22+-III+-%22I'll%22+-i'll&hl=en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099,vw:l&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=3v-mTamVOcnL0QHAiYD5CA&ved=0CBIQpwUoAA). I'd say at least a quarter of these ~700 listings since 2000 match the usage in question. You're right, not standard, but I'd argue not rare either.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Rather depends on your definition of *rare* (are we talking *Yttrium* or *Hen's teeth*?). Personally I think the usage is ill[-]iterate, but certainly there's no denying it *does* occur.